# JAVA - Press button when user hits enter java swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a guessing game where the user enters a number from 1 to 10 and tries to guess the right one.

I have a button in a window that starts a new game:

```
    btnPlayAgain = new JButton("Play Again!");
    btnPlayAgain.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            newGame();
        }
    });
    btnPlayAgain.setBounds(146, 115, 141, 21);
    getContentPane().add(btnPlayAgain);
    btnPlayAgain.setVisible(false);
```

I want the user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and have the button get clicked.

This is [all my code:](https://pastebin.com/F3h8Bdu9). This is what the window with the play again button looks like: [image: Guessing Game Window]

How can I get that play again button to click when the user hits that button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the answer is correct, you can set the default button of the `JFrame` to the play again button.

```
btnGuess.setVisible(false);
txtGuess.setVisible(false);
message = guess + " is correct. Let's play again!";
btnPlayAgain.setVisible(true);
getRootPane().setDefaultButton(btnPlayAgain);
```

When the `newGame` method is called, you can reset the default button to `null`.

```
public void newGame() {
    numberOfTries = 8;
    theNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    btnGuess.setVisible(true);
    txtGuess.setVisible(true);
    btnPlayAgain.setVisible(false);
    lblOutput.setText("Enter a number above and click Guess!");
    getRootPane().setDefaultButton(null);
}
```